# parse json from recipepuppy in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to make a java command line tool that lets you enter the name of any food and it will give you more information about it, such as the ingredients and image links. To get the data, I am using the recipe puppy API. I have managed to get the json from recipe puppy into a string, which I'm calling mFoodJson.

Now I want to get able to get the json content of the string and be able to access it in an array like form, so for example, I could get the first result for a search for pizza in recipe puppy and return the ingredients somewhat like this (assuming mFoodJson contains the json from recipe puppy)

```
String[] mFoodArray = mFoodJson.toArray();
System.out.println("Ingredients in " + mFoodQuery + ": " + mFoodArray[1].ingredients;
```

An example of the json that recipe puppy returns from their API would be somewhat like this (assuming the food searched for was "pizza"):

```
{
    "title":"Recipe Puppy",
    "version":0.1,
    "href":"http:\/\/www.recipepuppy.com\/",
    "results": 
    [
        {
            "title":"BBQ Chicken Pizza",
            "href":"http:\/\/www.recipezaar.com\/BBQ-Chicken-Pizza-144689",
            "ingredients":  "chicken, brown sugar, cayenne, garlic salt, green pepper, honey, italian cheese blend, salad dressing, margarine, molasses, onions, barbecue sauce, black pepper, prepared pizza crust, provolone cheese, ranch dressing, salt",
            "thumbnail":""
        },
        {
            "title":"Basic Chicago-style Pizza Recipe",
            "href":"http:\/\/www.grouprecipes.com\/65487\/basic-chicago-style-pizza.html",
            "ingredients":  "pizza, vegetable oil,cornmeal, water, flour, sausage, provolone cheese, olive oil, tomato, yeast, pepperoni, salt, salt, sugar, basil, oregano",
            "thumbnail":""
        },
        {
            "title":"BBQ'd Cheeseburger Pizza",
            "href":"http:\/\/www.recipezaar.com\/BBQd-Cheeseburger-Pizza-299376",
            "ingredients":  "barbecue sauce, cheddar cheese, onions, tomato, dill pickle, dill relish, parsley, french dressing, garlic powder, ground beef, lettuce, mayonnaise, mozzarella cheese, pizza dough, mustard",
            "thumbnail":"http:\/\/img.recipepuppy.com\/152332.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There are plenty json parsers out there like Jackson, Gson or LoganSquare. Google for them.